# Angular how to upload the file string, but NOT the physical file itself

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, jspdf

I have an angular app that generate a pdf string and want to upload it (encoded uri, or raw data option). 
I know that for a physical file, you can do the upload, but what about the pdf string generated within the app? is there a way to upload such?

My code is something like this:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
var str = doc.output('datauristring'); // this will be uri encoded string
var raw = doc.output();
var myForm = new FormData();
myForm.append('file', <what should go here??>);
//...
// POST myForm to backend
```